# Setting window.pageYOffset in Firefox doing nothing?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using the most recent version of Firefox.

I'm just trying to get the window to scroll back to the position it was before submitting a form.

In the html head of the page there's the code:

    `if (sessionStorage.top !== null) {
        window.pageYOffset = sessionStorage.top;
    }`

and later a validation function is called that has the following line in it:

    `sessionStorage.top = window.pageYOffset;`

Since this function submits a form the page is automatically reloaded.

I've verified that the validation function is called, executing all the way through including the line above.

I've verified that the code in html head is being executed (including inside the if statement - `sessionStorage.top` is not null.

I've verified that both `sessionStorage.top` and `window.pageYOffset` are set to 630.

Yet the window stays at position 0 (zero).

I've tried setting `window.pageYOffset` directly to 630 and this also does nothing. The page stays at the topmost (default) position.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is readonly? Use `window.scrollTop = offsetValue;` to set the scroll position.

Comment: No joy. Replacing occurrences of `window.pageYOffset` with `window.scrollTop` makes no difference. Had a scan through my css to see if there's a conflict but can't find one.

Comment: So when are you setting it? Could you be setting it before the content has loaded and the page has no ability to scroll to the correct location?

Comment: that's quite possible. I'm setting it first thing. I'll try putting it later on the page and see if that works. I've noticed a delay before the page scrolls on other websites that do this. This is probably why.

Comment: Tried putting the if condition at the bottom of the page just before the closing body and html tags. Do I maybe need to run some code to know when the page is fully loaded? This would be a shame because there are external videos in iframes that delay the page loading a lot but the layout is fixed way before they load.

Comment: Ok, will try onload.

Comment: Crumbs, this thing just ain't budging. I changed the opening body tag to  `<body onload="scrollIt()">` and put the code setting `window.scrollTop` into a function called `scrollIt()`. There must be something else going on here. This code should work.

Comment: Ugh I give up. Tried a JS solution called [ScrollSneak](http://mrcoles.com/scroll-sneak/) and adapted it to my webpage. That didn't work either. There must be something about my webpage that is blocking it.